# ASP.NET MVC for REST endpoints

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, semantic-web, endpoint

I would like to know if it is a good idea to use asp.net MVC for defining a REST endpoints.
I have a virtuoso server running on my machine, and my idea is to develop application that will use default sparql endpoint in virtuoso to be able to query data.

I'm thinking by developing asp.net mvc application that will define new endpoints for example /Teacher/{teacherID} and so users will not be directly manipulating results from sparql endpoint.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Slightly off topic so only commenting but you could use my library dotNetRDF (http://www.dotnetrdf.org) in your app since that will let you talk directly to Virtuoso directly via OpenLink's Virtuoso ADO.Net provider so avoids the extra overheads of having to make HTTP requests to your Virtuoso endpoints in your app.  It also gives you a comprehensive API for manipulating RDF and SPARQL Results in-memory

Comment: Hello. I'm using API that Virtuoso provides for .NET applications (OpenLink.Data.Virtuoso). API gives access to common ADO.NET objects like IdbConnection, IdbCommand and others. I was able to query data using sparql and then access it through IDataReader. This project is for my Bachelor Degree and in addition I would like to implement a simple web application which basically contains REST endpoints. I was wondering what strategy can be adopted in this case? I don't know if for example with asp.net mvc I can map this kind of url -> "Location/University/Teachder/{teacherID}".